# Does DjangoCMS open a database connection EACH time a user access a page?

Tags: mysql, django, caching, django-cms

As I mentioned in the  title "Does Django CMS open a database connection EACH time a user access a page?"

The problem is even though I saw on this  [page](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.3.x/how_to/caching.html)  that it caches my pages by default, everytime I refresh/change pages a new MySQL connection is being opened.

How would I cache my pages so my MySQL connections would happen only at the first time.

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/4.1/tutorial/introduction.html

Answer (score 1):

There are different levels of cache's you might be talking about, you can use any kind of Database Cache by using Cache Databases like [Redis](http://redis.io/), [Memcache](https://memcached.org/) these can be used to cache the query result from the database itself, so that you don't have to open and run the query each time.

You have mentioned that every time a page is being rendered a new connection is opening is opened,  you may want to use something like [Varnish](https://memcached.org/). This can be used to cache the HTTP Response so the query doesn't even get to the django application. This makes your response way faster since it will be rendered like a static page.

This would improve the application if you have huge number of request's in a small time frame

Comment: Thanks for your help, I read about caching (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/) in Django but maybe I misunderstood something but I thought that I could serve my pages as static files using djangocms after generating some content. When I saw the use cases I'd see companies like Nasa and Ubuntu that certantly would handle a lot of traffic. Maybe they did some customization to get where they are. I'll study some more and see my options.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

**THIS STATEMENT BELOW IS WRONG**

This  [page](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.3.x/reference/settings-constants.html#std:setting-CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CACHE)  explains that you can't be in "edit_off=false" so I changed to "true" and it worked.